# Hyperlink not coming in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater in which I have to set hyperlink for binding link, i tried in the below code but it is not working.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <div class="Newsdivalign">
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hytitle" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("title") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `src` is a valid parameter for the HyperLink control. You need to set `Text` for the description and `NavigateURL` for the URL.

Not tested, but something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hytitle" runat="server" 
    Text='<%#Eval("title") %>' NavigateURL='<%#Eval("url") %>' 
</asp:HyperLink>
```